# Missing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics during Web Role deployment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Using Visual Studio 2012 RC, from the page, I started an Azure Cloud Service. I selected MVC 4, included a test project, and enabled NuGet package restores on build.

When I deployed this to an Azure Web Site, using git, it seems that the target box does not include either the `WindowsAzure.Diagnostics` *or* the `WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` libraries. I'm new to .NET in general, but I can't imagine what I'm missing here. Furthermore, while I can trivially remove Diagnostics from the references (no diagnostics, no problem), it doesn't seem that I can do the same with ServiceRuntime.

**Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Azure Web Sites? Is it fixable?**

```
C:\... [master]> git push azure master
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 216.47 KiB, done.
Total 12 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: New deployment received.
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '2cb9c59bd0'.
remote: Building web project 'MvcWebRole1.csproj'.
remote: ..
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.0.0-beta2'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'jQuery.Validation 1.8.1'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core 1.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDb 1.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'jQuery.UI.Combined 1.8.11'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.6.2'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax 2.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 2.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 2.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Modernizr 2.0.6'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20505.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'WebGrease 1.0.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0-rc'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'WindowsAzure.Storage 1.7.0.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'knockoutjs 2.0.0'.
remote:   Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.1'.
remote: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resol
ve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your
code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\barf\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\MvcWebRole1\MvcWebRole1
.csproj]
remote: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resol
ve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutra
l, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by yo
ur code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\barf\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\MvcWebRole1\MvcWebRo
le1.csproj]
remote: WebRole.cs(5,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Diagnostics' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\barf\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Mv
cWebRole1\MvcWebRole1.csproj]
remote: WebRole.cs(6,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceRuntime' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\barf\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\MvcWebRole1\MvcWebRole1.csproj]
remote: WebRole.cs(10,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RoleEntryPoint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\barf\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\MvcWebRole1\Mvc
WebRole1.csproj]
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but your website not updated.
```

Comment: have you checked to see if there is an errant file on the server that is causing the referencing error?  accordig to http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2012/08/08/git-deployment-to-an-azure-website-keeping-configuration-secrets.aspx, the kudu deployment engine which powers the git deployments here will NOT delete and files on the target, even if removed from source.  you might ftp in and see if there are some dlls in your bin dir on the server that shouldn't be there... or delete them all and re-deploy fresh...

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well, I think part of it has to do with the path that the dlls are located at. My project appears to reference C:\ProgramFiles for those dlls instead of a project specific path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error you are getting because of assembly reference.

If installed Microsoft SDK, the references will be there in reference folder.If its not there then we have to browse add into Solution.Even i got the same problem while running the solution.Now i resolved this problem and its working fine.

If we installed windows azure sdk

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10\ref"

all the references will be here.just add this references in to your solution and build it, will work.

Hope this may helpful,

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448
downloaded each of them and installed. works now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429867/azure-git-deployment-missing-references-in-2nd-assembly

Answer (score 4):

This question is clearly answered.

However, the easiest resolution is to add the [AzureSDK2.2DLLs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureSDK2.2DLLs/) to your web role project(s).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are using Visual Studio 2012 Release Candidate and the Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio 2012 have not yet released.  Try the same code with Visual Studio 2010 and all your assemblies should be found and issues resolved.