# Azure git deployment - missing references in 2nd assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, deployment, azure, web-deployment

I'm trying to setup Bitbucket deployment to an Azure website. I successfully have Bitbucket and Azure linked, but when I push to Bitbucket, I get the following error on the Azure site:

[image]

If I click on 'View Log', it shows the following compile errors:

```
    D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    CustomMembershipProvider.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebMatrix' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    CustomMembershipProvider.cs(9,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExtendedMembershipProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    Models\AccountModels.cs(3,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    CustomMembershipProvider.cs(198,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OAuthAccountData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    Models\AccountModels.cs(40,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    Models\AccountModels.cs(40,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CompareAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    Models\AccountModels.cs(73,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
    Models\AccountModels.cs(73,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CompareAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<projname>\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\<projname>.Common\<projname>.Common.csproj]
```

Note that these compile errors are against another assembly in my project (the assembly where I put the business logic).

When Googling, the only mention I found was about having to set the "local copy" flag to true for those references. I've tried this, but still got the same errors.

This all compiles fine locally. Any ideas?

### Update

To add a bit more information, my project structure that is in the Git repo is as follows:

```
+ProjName
    ProjName.csproj
    web.config
    ...etc...
+ProjName.Common
    ProjName.Common.csproj
+ProjName.Tests
    ProjName.Tests.csproj
+packages <-- these are Nuget packages
ProjName.sln
```

The compile errors shown by Azure say that it's ProjName.vcproj that failed - but they refer to the ProjName.Common assembly reference.

Note that this layout is what VisualStudio created (ie. an extra project subdirectory for the webroot).

I'm not really sure what Azure does when doing a Git deploy. Does it recognise that the ProjName directory is the webroot, and also parse the ProjName.sln compiling any other assemblies that are in the solution (the same way Visual Studio does)?

Also, I've not added any "bin" folders to Git. However, I did just try this as a test, and it didn't change the compile errors that Azure produced.

Comment: Check [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446226/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc4-application-with-sql-server-ce-to-azure-website/12500023#12500023). FTP is a great debug tool for Windows Azure Web Sites.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what files need to be in the git repo. I don't have my bin folder checked into git (I presume Azure generates this in the same way as VS does when I compile locally?). When I FTP in, the <projname>.Common (which is my business logic assembly) has an empty bin folder (presumably because it failed to compile). And the folder that is my web root doesn't have a bin directory at all (presumably because the <projname>.Common which failed to compile is a required dependancy).

Comment: @Dan. It depends. Are you using any dll's that are not in an oridnary windows installation you will need to provide them. Did you follow this guide when setting it all up? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson I'm not using anything that's not in the nuget "packages" directory, or the <projname>.Common project that's included in the solution (so I presume that Azure would compile this).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Updated 11/25/2012: After looking at Dan's repo, the problem is that the library project is using Mvc 4 from the GAC instead of using the NuGet package. Switching to the NuGet package makes it work fine on Azure.

In theory, MVC4 could be in the GAC on the Azure machines and this would not be an issue. And maybe they'll get there at some point. Though generally, the MVC team is increasingly pushing a NuGet based model where you don't rely on things being in the GAC.

Original answer:

Generally, you should avoid committing binaries to your git repo, instead relying on NuGet to retrieve them. Please see https://github.com/KuduApps/Mvc4ApplicationFx40WithLib for a sample project that does this and works fine in Azure Web Sites.

But based on your project structure, I see that your projects seem to use C++ (.vcproj). If so, then the likely problem is that C++ may not be supported today in Azure Web Sites when publishing via git. So far, I don't think this has come up as must people use C# & VB. If that is indeed the issue, then I suggest you open an issue on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu so we can properly track this.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally typed .vcproj into the question (I'm from a C++ background, so this is what my hands autotyped!). The extension is actually .csproj. I'll update my question.

Comment: I can't see anything the kudo project which is different than my layout. We both have extra projects in the solution aswell as the MVC webroot part, and no bin files are included. If Azure is compiling this automatically for you when you push your changes, then at least I know there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the way that I'm doing it.

Comment: If you're able to share a repo (e.g. on GitHub) which has the issue, I can take a look and can probably figure it out. It doesn't have to be your full repo if you have private stuff in there. Anything that has enough to show the problem will do.

Comment: David - I could kiss you. I had a moved my MVC models to their own project, one model used an MVC type so resharper added a GAC reference. Git>Azure then threw a deployment wobbly. Thanks to you I removed the mvc .dll and applied MVC via Nuget and all is now well. x1000 thanks- my weekend is saved

Answer (score 2):

So my .Common assembly had a reference to System.Web.Mvc and WebMatrix.WebData, and it looks like Azure doesn't support that. I had some membership code which used those references in the common assembly rather the web project. Removing those, removes the error. I'll have to refactor the code slightly so that the common library doesn't require these references.

Comment: Was it my comment that led you to this? I would love the bounty since you 'll lose it anyway :)

Comment: To be honest, it was more David's comment about creating a test project that demonstrates the problem. I tried this, but my test project worked fine. So I then took another look at my project that breaks it, and worked it out by trial and error. Seems a bit silly that bounty is lost if you answer your own question.

Comment: Aiit! On the bounty issue I guess there might have been people keeping their bounties after engaging SO users to help them out which led to this "new" system where you will always lose your bounty.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Would still be interesting to see a small repro, so we can get to the bottom of it. Normally, if it builds on your machine, it should ideally build on Azure as well.

Comment: I've created a test project which shows this issue. Note that I had to both add a reference to system.web.mvc, and also use it (see my last commit where I just created a dummy instance of the AjaxHelper class). Without this usage, it didn't show the error - I presume the reference was optimised out because it wasn't used. Repo is here: https://bitbucket.org/dracan/azuretest. Note that this compiles file locally.

Comment: Thanks Dan. The problem is that the library is using Mvc from the GAC instead of using the NuGet package. Switching to the NuGet package makes it work fine on Azure.

Comment: Ah. I would have thought that a common reference like system.web.mvc would be in Azure's GAC. Feel free to add an answer saying that was the problem, and I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: Amazing. I had this EXACT same problem. I would have never figured out from the error messages that removing the reference to WebData would have been the problem. Thank you to all above for your research into this issue. MASSIVE kudos!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today at the azure bootcamp.

Enabling Nuget Package Restore on the solution and commiting those changes to the github repo enabled a successful deployment